# Parallelism: Memory system that gives the illusion of being large, cheap and fast

Tags: memory, parallel-processing, cpu, cpu-architecture

My professor mentioned in the class that there are two ways in which we can  create  a  memory  system  that  gives  the  illusion  of  being  large,cheap  and  fast?

The first one being - Memory Hierarchy
and second one - Parallelism.

I wanted to know how parallelism plays a role in making such an illusion.

Comment: Not sure what your prof means exactly.  Each core can have its own fast private caches, giving you more fast cache.  Or [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) (e.g. Hyperthreading)
 can hide cache-miss latency, giving you throughput but not helping with single-thread performance.  Other CPUs like UltraSPARC Niagara were designed around SMT to hide cache miss latency, without bothering with good single-thread performance.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraSPARC_T1).  Do either of those fit the context of what your prof said?  I wouldn't have said that.

Comment: @PeterCordes I suspect the professor *was* referring to using parallelism to mask latency. The Tera Multithreaded Architecture was an extreme example of such latency hiding with 128 threads/instruction streams per processor. The Tera MTA did not use cache but directly accessed memory. The idea of parallelism hiding latency is simply that while waiting for one operation to complete other operations can be performed (this applies at the instruction level, the operation level (e.g., vector operations executed at less than full width), and thread level).